# Postgres/VectorPG expects string for some reason

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

Basically I want to adapt this Colab Notebook from Google for my own project: https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/pgvector/notebooks/pgvector_gen_ai_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=hZKe_9qeRdMH

I created a Postgres SQL database on GCP and created a table using the following code:

```
import os
import asyncio
import asyncpg
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector
from pgvector.asyncpg import register_vector

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    async with Connector(loop=loop) as connector:
        # Create connection to Cloud SQL database
        conn: asyncpg.Connection = await connector.connect_async(
            # Cloud SQL instance connection name
            f"{project_id}:{region}:{instance_name}",
            "asyncpg",
            user=f"{database_user}",
            password=f"{database_password}",
            db=f"{database_name}"
        )
        await conn.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS vector")
        await register_vector(conn)
        try:
            await conn.execute("DROP TABLE my_table")
            print("Table dropped successfully!")
        except:
            print("Table does not exist")

        # Create the `my_table` table.
        await conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE my_table(
                                chunk_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                                file_name TEXT,
                                content TEXT,
                                contentVector vector(1536))""")

        print("Table created successfully!")
        await conn.close()
```

This code works fine. The table is successfully created. Note that I **specified** the contentVector to be of type **"vector"**. And I also enable the vector extension as shown in the colab tutorial.
If I retrieve the schema of my table I get back the following:

```
<Record column_name='contentvector' data_type='USER-DEFINED'>
<Record column_name='chunk_id' data_type='text'>
<Record column_name='file_name' data_type='text'>
<Record column_name='content' data_type='text'>
```

I think it's a bit wierd that it now states **data_type='USER-DEFINED'** instead of 'vector' but maybe it's supposed to work that way. I don't know.
Anyways I tried to insert some data from a json with the following code:

```
# Same connection stuff as shown above 
        insert_statement = """
        INSERT INTO my_table(chunk_id, file_name, content, contentVector) 
        VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)
        ON CONFLICT (chunk_id) 
        DO NOTHING
        """
        for record in data:
            # Execute the INSERT statement
            await conn.execute(insert_statement, record['chunk_id'], record['file_name'], record['content'], np.array(record['contentVector']))
```

I tried with and without the np.array part (np.array part was done in the colab tutorial as well). But I get the following error:

```
File "asyncpg/protocol/prepared_stmt.pyx", line 197, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $4: array([ 0.02754428,  0.0151995 ,  0.0026... (expected str, got ndarray)
```

If I don't transform my data using np.arry it says "got list" instead of "got ndarray".
But the biggest question to me **why** is it expecting a **string**? I have no idea how this vector db magic works but I'm pretty sure that a str can't be the right data type for this.

Comment: Why are you so sure when even the [getting started](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#getting-started) clearly shows strings?

Comment: Interesting...
But if the data type is actually a string how can this colab code from google work?
In their example they are converting it to a numpy array: np.array(row["embedding"]) Shouldn't this be impossible if the vector data type only accepts strings?

Comment: What do you get if you try pull the schema in the colab book or can't you do that? Does it still show `USER-DEFINED`?

Comment: Can't really execute the Colab notebook without some effort to configure it on my envrionment and use my data.
But I just tried to convert my contentVector to a string and it successfully inserted the data. So I assume that this works. However I'm still confused why it is a string. How do you calculate a cosine distance between two 2 strings. This does not make much sense to me. Unless postgres is doing some transformation in the backend that I'm unaware of

Comment: That's a representation of the data that you are inserting but it doesn't mean that it's treated as a string when you're running it. It's been doing magic on [json/jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for some time now. I don't really know how it works, but it definitely isn't treating stuff as a string literal once it's in the database

Comment: I just tried calculating the cosine distance and it works like a charm. So yeah turns out there was nothing wrong with my code whatsoever. Should have just passed a string first before asking a question....

Comment: Meh, it's non-obvious that a string should be treated this way. You might as well answer your own question to that effect since someone else might get tripped up on this.